# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str while parsing json requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have some problem, i learn using request and json but i have this problem

`r2 = requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
usdt_btc_ask = r2.json(['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk'])`

and error

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

this code is working without error

`r1 = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
print(r1.json()['time']['updated']['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'])`

how to pharse this or some fix this problem?

Comment: `r2.json(['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk'])` You defined a list `['USDT_BTC']` - and then tried to index into it with `['lowestAsk']`. That's not how indexing works. Your second example has got it right.

Comment: `usdt_btc_ask = r2.json(['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk'])` --> `usdt_btc_ask = r2.json()['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk']` .. try that.

Comment: In your *working* example you are indexing the return value of the .json call ... r1.json **(** **)** ['stuff']. In your *non-working* example you passed the *indices* **to** the .json call ... r2.json **(** ['stuff'] **)**.

Comment: This working 

`r2 = requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
usdt_btc_ask = r2.json()['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk']`

but if i add one more (like this) see the same problem 

`r2 = requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
usdt_btc_ask = r2.json()['USDT_BTC']['lowestAsk']['highestBid']`

 string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the response from `requests.get` by doing `req.json()`, which will give you a dictionary on which you can iterate.

In your case, `json_obj['time']['updated']` gives you a string, not a dictionary, so you cannot do `json_obj['time']['updated']['bpi']` on it.

```
import requests

r1 = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
json_obj = r1.json()
print(json_obj['time']['updated'])
#Apr 20, 2019 14:43:00 UTC
```